# Adsorptive part of the following diagram

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory

Suppose the the process [image] in the anomalous abelian gauge theory.

The longitudinal part of the corresponding amplitude is
$$
\tag 2 M_{||}(p) \sim \int d^{4}q \frac{\epsilon_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}q^{\alpha}p^{\beta}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha'\beta'}q_{\alpha'}p_{\beta'}}{(q^{2} + i0)((q - p)^{2}+i0)} \sim \int d^{4}q \frac{(q^{2}p^{2} - (q\cdot p)^{2})}{(q^{2}+i0)((q-p)^{2}+i0)}
$$
People claim that its imaginary part is **finite** and proportional to $p^{4}\theta(p^{2})$. However, I can't obtain this result. Precisely, I stuck on
$$
\text{Im}M_{||}(p) \sim -\int d^{4}q \frac{(q\cdot p)^{2}}{(q - p)^{2}}\delta (q^{2})\theta (q_{0}) + \int d^{4}q \frac{q^{2}p^{2} - (q\cdot p)^{2}}{p^{2}}\delta ((q - p)^{2})\theta(q_{0} - p_{0})
$$

**An edit**

I can calculate the initial amplitude $(2)$ by using Feynman parameters and Wick rotation:
$$
M(p) = -p^{2}\lim_{d\to 4}\frac{i}{(4\pi)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\frac{\Gamma\left(2 - \frac{d}{2}-1 \right)}{\Gamma(2)}\frac{d-1}{2}\int \limits_{0}^{1}dx \frac{1}{\left(-\frac{p^{2}}{\mu^{2}}x(1-x) - i\epsilon\right)^{2 - \frac{d}{2}-1}}
$$
By using
$$
\frac{1}{A^{2 - \frac{d}{2}}} \approx 1 - \left( 2 - \frac{d}{2}\right)\text{ln}(A)+O\left(\left(2 - \frac{d}{2}\right)^{2}\right), \quad \Gamma\left(2 -\frac{d}{2} - 1\right) = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{d}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2 - \frac{d}{2}}-\gamma \right)
$$
and setting $2 - \frac{d}{2} \equiv \varepsilon$ I obtain
$$
M(p) \approx \frac{3ip^{4}}{32\pi^{2}}\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int \limits_{0}^{1}dx x(1-x)\left[ \frac{1}{\varepsilon}- \text{ln}\left(-\frac{p^{2}}{\mu^{2}}x(1-x) - i\epsilon\right)\right] \approx
$$
$$
\approx |\text{ln}(-a-i\epsilon) = \text{ln}(a) - i\pi \theta(a)| \approx
$$
$$
\approx \frac{3ip^{4}}{32\pi^{2}}\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int \limits_{0}^{1}dx x(1-x)\left[ \frac{1}{\epsilon} + i\pi \theta(p^{2})\right] = \frac{ip^{4}}{64\pi^{2}} - \frac{p^{4}\theta(p^{2})}{64\pi}
$$
But only the real part of this expression gives $p^{4}\theta(p^{2})$ with finite coefficient. I don't understand where the extra factor $i$ is missed.

Comment: Perhaps: did you try to combine denominators via Feynman's parametric integration? It seems to me that it could be useful here. Also, I wouldn't expand the imaginary part yet. Calculate the full result in dim.reg. and extract the imaginary part using $\log (-a-i\epsilon)=\log a-i\pi$ for $a>0$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform : Oh, indeed. Thank You!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform : however by using
$$
\int \frac{d^{d}p}{(2\pi)^{4}}\frac{p^{2}}{(p^{2} - \Delta)^{2}} = i\frac{1}{(4\pi)^{\frac{d}{2}}}\frac{\Gamma\left( 2 - \frac{d}{2}-1\right)}{\Gamma(2)}\frac{1}{\Delta^{2 - \frac{d}{2}-1}}
$$ 
I find
$$
M_{||}(p) = i\frac{d - 1}{d}\frac{k^{2}}{(2 \pi)^{4}}\frac{\Gamma\left(2 - \frac{d}{2}-1\right)}{\Gamma(2)}\mu^{d}\int \limits_{0}^{1} dx \frac{1}{(k^{2}x(1-x)+i0)^{2 - \frac{d}{2}-1}},
$$
whose imaginary part seems to be logatithmically divergent (unlike the statement I've heard).

Comment: Hmm but
$$
\int \limits_{0}^{1} dx \frac{1}{(k^{2}x(1-x)+i0)^{2 - \frac{d}{2}-1}}\overset{d=4}=\frac{k^2}{6}
$$, right? So at least the dependence is $k^4$ as you wanted to prove. Maybe you should introduce an IR regulator.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform : yes, and the total value is pirely imaginary and diverges logarithmically.